# GRUB/bootloader and hard disk lost after update to Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I have a Surface 3 2GB (non-Pro) that had both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 17.04 installed on it as a dual boot config. During the update to 17.10, somehow I lost the ability for anything to see the main eMMC disk and also the bootloader.

I was updating ubuntu to the latest 17.10 in the terminal when it asked if I wanted to autoremove ~200 packages, and I wrote 'n', thinking I would remove them later. The terminal then spat out `---LOGGING ERROR---` and the entire system froze. I tried to rescue system by opening a new terminal, with the Alt+F2 and Alt+Ctrl+F1 commands, which seemed to kill the GUI but showed one short message that looked like a boot log message with the green `[   OK   ]`, but seemed frozen and didn't allow me to enter any commands. I proceeded to use REISUM, getting to the last one when it rebooted. Once it rebooted, it landed me on the UEFI boot options screen. This means that GRUB or any other bootloader cannot be loaded. I get no GRUB rescue or warning message that I've lost my MBR or anything.

I currently have the device on a live usb of ubuntu 17.10. It cannot detect the main disk drive at all. Boot-repair log [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25777289/). There should be a 64GB disk detected. A Windows 10 installer USB also cannot detect any drives, or perform startup repair. I have tried booting with secure boot on/off (off before) and Trusted Platform Management or whatever on/off (on before). There is no option to see detected hardware in BIOS. I can't run `ntfsfix` or `mount` on a drive that is not detected.

Any way to re-detect the main SSD is welcomed, but I suspect most of the data on the drive is still intact, so it would be best if I could simply rebuild the boot/drive table or something.

Comment: I think the most probable explanation is that the SSD inside my device is dead. It's unlikely since it's a refurbished unit less that one year old, but still possible due to the low quality eMMC flash in this device.

Comment: I concur; if neither Ubuntu nor Windows can detect the SSD, then chances are it (or circuitry required for it to be accessed) is dead. The fact that the failure occurred during an Ubuntu OS update is suspicious and suggests another cause; but it could be coincidence, or it could be that the unusually high level of disk activity during the update may have triggered a hardware failure.

Answer (score 0):

don't rush out and buy a replacement SSD - something might be going on here.  Have been working on getting an older Toshiba nb205 (updated with a 500 gb SSD) resetup with Lubuntu.  Have wiped and installed Lubuntu several times in the last few days and an install of 17.04 boots just fine.  Load 17.10 and it locks up after a terminal screen listing a few details about the drive.  Go back to 17.04 - works fine.

Comment: Literally nothing can see the disk. Not windows, not any Linux distros. I can't put another SSD into the device anyway, its glued shut and the SSD is soldered onto the mainboard.